# App freezes on start giving "E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed" messages in logcat

Tags: java, android, logcat, garbage

My app is freezing on start giving continous "E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed" messages in logcat. I am not sure what can be the problem. Sometimes it starts nice, but sometimes freezes throwing this messages. So where I should look for a problem? It gives me some Integer parsing errors before, but it is giving also when application starts properly, so I think it is not correlated?

```
       06-18 16:46:39.229  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4bca7000 size:6205440 offset:4669440 fd:50
06-18 16:46:39.599  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x4c312000 size:12165120 offset:10629120 fd:53
06-18 16:46:39.829  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:359)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.getHwFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.java:807)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.<init>(Calendar.java:745)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:338)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:239)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1086)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at com.example.krusty.drugi.MainActivity.ListDrwaer(MainActivity.java:227)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at com.example.krusty.drugi.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:197)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at com.example.krusty.drugi.MainActivity$JsonReadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:152)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
06-18 16:46:39.839  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
06-18 16:46:39.849  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 16:46:39.849  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 16:46:39.849  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-18 16:46:39.849  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 16:46:39.849  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 16:46:39.849  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
06-18 16:46:39.849  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
06-18 16:46:39.849  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 16:46:41.279  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 808K, 13% free 9755K/11107K, paused 4ms+6ms
06-18 16:46:43.119  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 722K, 11% free 10073K/11299K, paused 6ms+13ms
06-18 16:46:44.429  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 986K, 13% free 10127K/11619K, paused 4ms+15ms
06-18 16:46:46.819  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1007K, 14% free 10161K/11683K, paused 4ms+16ms
06-18 16:46:48.139  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1012K, 14% free 10190K/11747K, paused 3ms+9ms
06-18 16:46:49.059  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 950K, 13% free 10282K/11747K, paused 4ms+10ms
06-18 16:46:50.229  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1021K, 14% free 10303K/11875K, paused 5ms+9ms
06-18 16:46:51.309  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1034K, 14% free 10311K/11875K, paused 8ms+18ms
06-18 16:46:52.239  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1013K, 13% free 10339K/11875K, paused 3ms+9ms
06-18 16:46:53.069  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1042K, 14% free 10340K/11939K, paused 2ms+10ms
06-18 16:46:53.859  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1024K, 14% free 10358K/11939K, paused 3ms+10ms
06-18 16:46:54.769  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1042K, 14% free 10359K/11939K, paused 2ms+9ms
06-18 16:46:55.739  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 14% free 10361K/11939K, paused 3ms+9ms
06-18 16:46:56.709  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1043K, 14% free 10361K/11939K, paused 3ms+12ms
06-18 16:46:57.679  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 14% free 10364K/11939K, paused 3ms+10ms
06-18 16:46:58.629  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 14% free 10367K/11939K, paused 3ms+12ms
06-18 16:46:59.569  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1043K, 14% free 10367K/11939K, paused 3ms+10ms
06-18 16:47:00.589  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 14% free 10369K/11939K, paused 3ms+9ms
06-18 16:47:01.489  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1043K, 14% free 10369K/11939K, paused 4ms+11ms
06-18 16:47:02.389  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 14% free 10372K/11939K, paused 3ms+11ms
06-18 16:47:03.199  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1043K, 14% free 10372K/11939K, paused 3ms+10ms
06-18 16:47:03.939  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 14% free 10375K/11939K, paused 3ms+9ms
06-18 16:47:04.709  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1043K, 14% free 10375K/11939K, paused 3ms+9ms
06-18 16:47:05.559  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 14% free 10378K/11939K, paused 3ms+9ms
06-18 16:47:06.369  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1043K, 14% free 10378K/11939K, paused 2ms+10ms
06-18 16:47:07.109  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1043K, 14% free 10378K/11939K, paused 2ms+9ms
06-18 16:47:07.939  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1040K, 14% free 10380K/11939K, paused 3ms+8ms
06-18 16:47:08.779  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1043K, 14% free 10380K/11939K, paused 3ms+10ms
06-18 16:47:09.519  25269-25269/com.example.krusty.drugi E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 1038K, 14% free 10386K/11939K, paused 3ms+9ms
```

Comment: Post that logcat sir!

Answer (score 1):

> NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Open you code, file `MainActivity.java` at line 227.

You are parsing a `Integer` (seems like with `Calendar`) that is "", throwing an `NumberFormatException` because "" is not considered as a number, unlike "0".

To solve your issue, check what you give to `Calendar`. One of its parameters should be in this case "", which is invalid.

You can avoid this by checking for `null` and empty strings with `TextUtils.isEmpty()`.

Comment: do you think this is related to gc_explicit messages?

Comment: Date alsoNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
this is line 227, is this the correct way of doing ?

Comment: `GC_EXPLICIT` is a message from the Dalvik VM about the Garbage Collector. So no.

Comment: Ok, i asked about GC_EXPLICIT messages which are causing app to freeze, that is my main concern here.

Comment: You're application as it is is crashing because of the issue I explained in my answer. Fix that first ;)